# Is a diagonalizable matrix of rank 1 normal?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{C}_{n \times n}$, and $A$ is diagonalizable of rank 1, must $A$ be normal? Here, $A$ normal means that $AA^* = A^*A$ where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, the matrix 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}
$$
is diagonalizable but not normal.  Notably, an upper triangular matrix is normal if and only if it is diagonal.